Enable JMX metrics in Ehcache 3.10.8
I am trying to write a simple hello world program using ehcache 3.8.10 version. It is working as expected. i was able to put and get the contents as shown below.

XML configuration
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core.xsd" >

    <!-- In-memory garbage collected authorisation provider cache cannot have more than 1000 elements
        Idle cache elements will be removed after 6 mins; elements older than 6 mins will be removed as necessary to make space -->
    <cache alias="authprovidercache">
        <key-type>java.lang.Object</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.Object</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl>360</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config>


Main program
package org.ehcache;

import org.ehcache.config.Configuration;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
import org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class AuthEhCache {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        Configuration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(AuthEhCache.class.getResource("/authEhcache.xml"));
        // Create a simple cache configuration
        CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(xmlConfig);
        cacheManager.init();
        Cache ehCache = cacheManager.getCache("authprovidercache", Object.class, Object.class);
        ehCache.put("a", "b");
        System.out.println(ehCache.get("a"));
    }
}





I want to enable metrics as mentioned here.
 <service>
        <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/>
    </service>

Error stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factories exist for interface org.ehcache.jsr107.Jsr107Service
    at org.ehcache.core.spi.ServiceLocator$DependencySet.with(ServiceLocator.java:271)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.resolveServices(EhcacheManager.java:152)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:125)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:115)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.<init>(EhcacheManager.java:107)
    at org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(CacheManagerBuilder.java:108)
    at org.ehcache.AuthEhCache.main(AuthEhCache.java:15)


If i change the package name to import javax.cache.Cache; and
import javax.cache.CacheManager; it started working because those xml changes are specific to JSR 107.
